# Updating database data from websocket

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I would like to update database data from a websocket. Specifically, when a user connects to a websocket, I would like to update a field in one of my models with the timestamp of when the user connected.

However, with the logic I have implemented, I am getting this error:

```
Exception inside application: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\security\websocket.py", line 37, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\signup\middleware.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\sessions.py", line 263, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\auth.py", line 185, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\routing.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\utils.py", line 51, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\consumer.py", line 73, in dispatch
    await handler(message)
  File "C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\signup\consumers.py", line 34, in websocket_connect
    result = (await self.update_timestamp(group_name))
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 414, in __call__
    ret = await asyncio.wait_for(future, timeout=None)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 455, in wait_for
    return await fut
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 57, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\channels\db.py", line 13, in thread_handler
    return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15512\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\asgiref\sync.py", line 455, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\15512\Desktop\django-project\peerplatform\signup\consumers.py", line 108, in update_timestamp
    serializer_class = UpdateProfileView(request)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This is what I have tried, this is in my consumers.py and is the function called when a user connects to the websocket:

```
class PracticeConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def websocket_connect(self, event):
        ...
        group_name = username_id
        result = (await self.update_timestamp(group_name))
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            '{}'.format(group_name),
            self.channel_name
        )
        await self.accept()
    ...
    @database_sync_to_async
    def update_timestamp(self, user_id):
        time = timezone.now().isoformat()
        request = dict({'method': 'PUT', 'connected_timestamp': time, 'user.id': self.user_id})
        serializer_class = UpdateProfileView(request)
        return User.objects.filter(user__id=user_id).values()
```

This is how my UpdateProfileView is written out:

```
class UpdateProfileView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UpdateUserSerializer
    def profile(request):
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
                serializer_user = UpdateUserSerializer(user, many=True)
                if serializer_user.is_valid():
                    serializer_user.save()
                    return Response(serializer_user)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return Response(data='no such user!', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you need a `self` in the `UpdateProfileView`'s `profile` function, like: `def profile(self, request):`

**But!** from what I'm seeing they usually use the function `update` and not `profile`

###### Example

- Also I updated to use `filter().first()`, it will return `None` if it doesn't find one. Try/Catch is sorta gross imo

```py
class UpdateProfileView(generics.UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UpdateUserSerializer
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'PUT':

            user = User.objects.filter(id=request.user.id).first()

            # # but `request.user` is a User Object!- You don't need to filter for it!
            # user = request.user

            if user:
                serializer_user = UpdateUserSerializer(user, many=True)
                if serializer_user.is_valid():
                    serializer_user.save()
                    return Response(serializer_user)
            else:
                return Response(data='no such user!', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)python
```